# P# not working on Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, prolog

This is my code on my C# main class.

```
PrologInterface pInterface = new PrologInterface();
Term R = SymbolTerm.MakeSymbol("7");
Predicate pred = new Es_Mayor_1(R, new ReturnCs(pInterface));
pInterface.SetPredicate(pred);
bool result = pInterface.Call();
```

And this is the Prolog source code ('es mayor' means 'is greater' in spanish). The code only has these two lines.

```
esMayor(X):-
    >(X, 5).
```

The program crashes and gives an unknown exception, and it seems it's because it doesn't recognize the comparison operations. I also tried using the common syntax `X>5`, but still, with no success.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'JJC.Psharp.Lang.PrologException' occurred in Psharp.dll
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: If you run your code in Visual Studio under the debugger, do you get more information from the exception?

Comment: In normal Prolog, `>` will only work if you have numbers (or arithmetic expressions) on both sides. Can it be that your `"7"` ends up being something else? For a start, you can try to instead use `X @> 5` in your Prolog code (which compares arbitrary terms), or maybe just `number(X)`, to see if your _X_ is a number at that point.

Comment: Can you give all the code of your C# program ? Is there a Prolog program associated with it ?

Answer (score 0):

After reading the doc, I think that Boris is right, you should write

```
IntegerTerm R = new IntegerTerm(7);
```

instead of

```
Term R = SymbolTerm.MakeSymbol("7");
```